# Validation on key-press and numlock key-press

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo numeric text box.When it is blank it accepts '.' from numlock key part and the content changes to 0.00 but it does not accepts '.' from the main part of keyboard how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you must be having its type as number add step attribute to it as `<input type="number" step="any" />`